# Blocked images in Outlook are much taller than when they are not blocked

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

Blocked images in Outlook are too tall. While the actual image is 50 pixels tall when not blocked, the image is several hundred pixels tall when blocked. I had the same issue in Yahoo explorer, Gmail explorer, and other explorer clients. I added inline style of max-height="200". That fixed the issue in those clients, but not in the Outlook clients.

Litmus is showing this issue affecting Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003 with images blocked. Unsure about other versions of Outlook. I am using mailchimp templates to built these emails with no structural modifications made yet. Here's a screenshot of the issue.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/udd9nb9vapt5tn7/Screenshot%202015-03-09%2014.25.38.png?dl=0

Here is the HTML tbody containing the image

```
<tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding:9px" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
                    <table align="left" width="100%" max-height="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">

                                    <a href="http://www.simplystamps.com/" title="" class="" target="_blank">
                                        <img align="left" alt="Simply Stamps Logo" src="http://simplystamps.com/enews/SimplyStampsLogo.jpg" width="520" style="max-width:520px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage">
                                    </a>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Other than media queries, there are no stylesheet CSS for mcnImageBlockOuter, mcnImageBlockInner, mcnImageContentContainer, mcnImageContent, but there is one rule for .mcnImage

```
    .mcnImage{
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
```

I am experienced with web HTML, but new to email HTML. I have several ideas for how to fix this issue, but because I have to run a time consuming inbox inspection for each idea, I'd like to propose them here so I can narrow down the possible solutions, hopefully down to one.

Applying max-height="200" to outer tbody, outer tr, outer td, inner table, inner tbody, inner tr, and/or inner td. Not sure which one.

Is line height the cause, and/or a solution here? Should I apply line-height="0", and if so, to which element?

I've seen mso-line-height-rule:exactly; used in somewhat related issues. Is that a solution here?

Are there any solutions not listed above you believe may fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `max-height` nor `line-height` are valid HTML attributes. The reason the blocked image is too tall is because you aren't setting the height of the image at all, and Outlook along with every other client assumes the image to be a square.

Outlook doesn't respect the `max-height` (or `max-width`) CSS rule either, so if you did `width="100%"` `height="auto"` (which is valid) you would still see the big placeholder image boxes regardless of the CSS.

My biggest recommendation for coding for Outlook (or email clients in general) - use as few CSS rules as possible, rely on valid HTML 4.xx attributes, and be as explicit as possible down to the pixels.

Comment: as for the vertical align rule- Outlook does support this, but a more reliable solution is to use `valign="bottom"` on the containing `td`

Comment: Also tables don't respect `height`. Set the `height` on the `td`

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding `height:50px !important;` The `!important` is required becaused there may be an internal class with `height:auto !important;`that you need to override.

You may also try using the height attribute, instead of css.

I've have had the issue with some email clients, in one case it was solved by just adding `height:XXpx;`, and in another I noticed that that was overriden by another `height: auto;`